# Graph API Score with GET method can't return score field

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook SDK 4.2.0 Android to create the leader scoreboard for my game. 
I post successfully my score with POST method at */me/scores* graphPath:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"success":true}, error: null}
```

However, when I try to GET the score at */me/scores* as well as */793295994100883/scores* (793295994100883 is my APP ID), I didn't see my score in JSON result string.

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[{"user":{"id":"Facebook USER-ID","name":"Facebook USER-NAME"}}]}, error: null}
```

In https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, It return my expected string when I get at */793295994100883?field=scores{score}*

```
  "scores": {
    "data": [
      {
        "score": 1234,
        "user": {
          "name": "Facebook USER-NAME",
          "id": "Facebook USER-ID"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "id": "793295994100883"
```

Please help with this issue. How can I get score with Facebook SDK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the Graph API is your app using? If it's v2.4, you have to specify each field you want to retrieve.

Have a look at my answer here:

- [Facebook only returning name and id of user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692355/facebook-only-returning-name-and-id-of-user/31692908#31692908)

Comment: My APP is using Graph API v2.4. I specified the Graph API version in GraphRequest function to smaller. But I got the same result. Could you explain more detail about specifing field in Java android to retrieve score data.

Comment: You need to add the `fields` parameter with all the fields to the URL request! As said in the docs...

Comment: Hi Tobi. I tried your way but It seems the URL is not correct. So, I created the Bundle with putString("fields", "scores{score}"); I also changed the grapPath to "/{APP-ID}" and it worked. Thanks.