# FBSDKGraphRequest Response Issue - Not getting scores

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am using following code to get the game score of my facebook friend.

```
    -(void)GetFriendScore
{
    NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]], @"access_token",
                                     nil];

    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"/me/scores"
                                  parameters:params
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {

    }];
}
```

and got the response in following formate

```
{
data =     (
            {
            user =             {
                id = XYZ;
                name = "XYZ";
            };
            }
            );
```

}

but this is not expected response.
my expected formate is following

```
{
data =     (

            {
            application =             {
                category = Games;
                id = XYZ;
                link = "https://www.facebook.com/games/?app_id=XYZ";
                name = "XYZ";
            };
            score = 2907;
            user =             {
                id = XYZ;
                name = "XYZ";
            };
            }
            );
```

}

can anyone please help me to get correct response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using Graph API v2.4. With that, you'll have to specify each field you want to have returned. See my answer for a similar question here:

- [Graph API Score with GET method can't return score field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684533/graph-api-score-with-get-method-cant-return-score-field/31693393#31693393)

You need to request `/{app_id}/scores?fields=user,application,score` instead of `/me/scores?fields=user,application,score` I guess if you also want to see the friend's scores

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/app/…

Alternatively,

```
/me?fields=scores{user,application,score},friends{scores{user,application,score}‌​}
```

should work as well

Comment: where i need to specify fields,can you please help me.

Comment: one issue is still there,this is unable to fetch friends score.Getting only user score.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using following code.

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"/me/scores?fields=user,application,score"
                              parameters:params
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

Comment: one issue is still there,this is unable to fetch friends score.Getting only user score.

Comment: You need to request `/{app_id}/scores?fields=user,application,score` instead of `/me/scores?fields=user,application,score`  I guess: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/app/scores alternatively, `me?fields=scores{user,application,score},friends{scores{user,application,score}}` should work as well

Answer (score 0):

How we can do same in android.i have same problem in android i am using following code

```
request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/ "+"FB_ID"+"/scores?fields=user,application,score", param , HttpMethod.GET);
if(request!=null)
{
    request.setCallback(new Request.Callback()
    {
        public void onCompleted(Response response)
        {
                    if(response!=null)
                    {
                        GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                        if(graphObject==null)
                        {
                            //getting graphObject NULL
                        }

                    }
        }
    }
}
```

how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

```
param.putString("fields", "user,application,score");
request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/me/scores", param , HttpMethod.GET);
if(request!=null)
{
    request.setCallback(new Request.Callback()
    {
        public void onCompleted(Response response)
        {
                    if(response!=null)
                    {
                        GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                        if(graphObject==null)
                        {
                            //Enjoy
                        }

                    }
        }
    }
}
```