# Facebook scores API not returning score data for 'me'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are having trouble querying scores from the Scores Graph API.

Using the Graph Explorer with an app access token, We query me/scores but the data the gets returned looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "user": {
        "name": "USER_NAME",
        "id": "APP_USER_ID"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, no score is returned.

Giving the app the publish_actions permission and submitting a new score returns successful, but still, querying scores returns the same data as before.

We have not changed anything on our end, so I'm wondering if something has changed on Facebook's side.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at my answer to a similar question here:

- [FBSDKGraphRequest Response Issue - Not getting scores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696095/fbsdkgraphrequest-response-issue-not-getting-scores/31696183#31696183)